# 405: Method Not Found on POST request

Tags: php, laravel, http

I am recieving the 405: Method not Found error when trying to perform a POST request on my laravel application. I'm trying to make a forum to learn how to use php and Laravel.
I am trying to post the request from `/forum/category/{category}/post`, I perform (almost) identical requests from just `/forum` and it works perfectly, so I assume it's something to do with this.
This is where I'm trying to post the request from (returns `post.blade.php`):

```
Route::get('forum/category/{category}/post', 'ForumController@showThreadPostForm');
```

The request:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'postthread',
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr('content')},
      data: {"test": "data"},
      success: function(res) {
        window.location.reload();
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("Error occured during AJAX request, error code: " + xhr.status);
      },
  });
});
```

The route:

```
Route::post('postthread', 'ForumController@postThread');
```

The controller method:

```
    public function postThread(Request $request) {
      //empty
    }
```

I'm not sure if this information is enough.
Thanks.

I've used the same AJAX request on a different page `/forum` and it works, I'm not sure how to make it work on this page.

Comment: Try to add a **/** forward slash before your Route and also to your ajax route.

Comment: Can you paste the post request's details, like the url, header, and body?

Comment: Thank you, adding a forward slash fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add token to your data and add slash to your url.

also meta tag set to:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/postthread',
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr('content')},
      data: {"test": "data",  "_token": $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr('content')},
      success: function(res) {
        window.location.reload();
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("Error occured during AJAX request, error code: " + xhr.status);
      },
  });
```